# Problems while installing Homebrew on my M2 MacBook Air running MacOS Ventura 13.0.1

Tags: macos, terminal, network, homebrew, apple-silicon

I am trying to install Homebrew on my personal MacBook Air connected to my personal Wi-Fi but I am getting the following error :

[image]

I have already tried switching to different networks and resetting my laptop but I can't solve this issue.

(P.S. I can't access https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh through my browser either). Please help me with this

Comment: Turn off firewalls, `Little Snitch`, `Lulu`, etc.

Comment: Might be overboard, make sure you're not using any strange DNS settings, like Cloudflare, etc...

Comment: I am not using any strange DNS settings and my firewall is off. This is a brand-new laptop,should I try resetting it and logging in with another apple ID instead?

Answer (score 2):

It was a problem with the Indian ISP "Jio". For some reason , devices connected to a Jio Network can't connect to raw.githubusercontent.com. I found a work around for this problem by adding the address 1.1.1.1 to the DNS settings of my WiFi. I would also recommend adding 1.0.0.1 for redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "System Settings" --> "network" and set DNS 8.8.8.8 in network will resolve this.

Comment: The error is “operation timed out” not “could not find host.”  The server didn’t respond; not that the server wasn’t found. Why would changing the server that handles name resolution fix this?

Comment: @allan if you look at the other answer, this actually might help.